# How can I run certain types of Ansible tasks (without tags)

Tags: ansible

I would like to regularly run my `copy` and `template` tasks (and some others) on all hosts to make sure configuration files are up to date.
I know about `tags`, but what if somebody forgets a tag on a `copy` task, for example?

Even better, can I exclude certain task types, like `apt`, which I am not interested in when checking configuration files?

Edit: add simplified example to hopefully make my question clearer.

I want to skip the `apt` task below and only run the `copy` and `template` task:

```
- name: install postfix                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
  apt: name=postfix update_cache=yes state=present

- name: postfix main.cf
  copy:
    src: roles/postfix/files/main.cf
    dest: /etc/opt/ooce/postfix/main.cf

- name: postfix aliases
  template:
    src: roles/postfix/files/aliases
    dest: /etc/aliases
```

Comment: You could split your tasks into multiple playbooks or roles.

Answer (score 0):

Your information is very high level. But if you're looking for skipping certain tasks then you can check "when" condition for filtering certain tasks to be run or skipped. Below is the sample from [Ansible documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_conditionals.html).

when:
  - ansible_facts['distribution'] == "CentOS"
  - ansible_facts['distribution_major_version'] == "6"